# Not able to perform Deep Insert operation for API_PRODUCT_SRV Standard WhiteListed API using S/4 Hana Cloud SDK

Tags: s4sdk, sap-cloud-sdk

I have completed read and update operations on `API_PRODUCT_SRV` Service.

Now while doing deep insert on `API_PRODUCT_SRV` (Product Entity-which has many associations) I am getting the following error.

```
“errordetails”: [

{
“code”: “API_PRD_MSG/004”,
“message”: “Provide atleast one description for the product.”,
“propertyref”: “”,
“severity”: “error”,
“target”: “”
}
]
```

I found this deep dive blog

https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/07/step-20-with-s4hana-cloud-sdk-create-and-deep-insert-with-the-virtual-data-model-for-odata/comment-page-1/#comment-453020

which explains the deep insert using servlets.(i.e Using HttpServletReq) which provides the rest service.

But I am using the `CreateRequest` class from SAP Cloud Application Programming Model which generates odata service, so that I cannot use the similar code which is presented in the blog.

I have added the code and the payload for your perusal.

Create Operation code

```
@Create(serviceName = "ProductService", entity = "Products")
    public CreateResponse create(CreateRequest req) throws ODataException {
        Product toCreate = new ModelMapper().map(req.getMapData(), Product.class);          
        Product created = new DefaultProductMasterService().createProduct(toCreate)
                .execute(new ErpConfigContext("K4XS4SDKDest"));
        return CreateResponse.setSuccess().setData(created).response();
    }
```

Payload being used:

```
{
  "Product" : "BALL",
    "ProductType" : "ZHLB",
    "CrossPlantStatus" : "",
    "CrossPlantStatusValidityDate" : null,
    "CreationDate" : "\/Date(1499731200000)\/",
    "CreatedByUser" : "11279380",
    "LastChangeDate" : "\/Date(1550448000000)\/",
    "LastChangedByUser" : "HWV87616",
    "IsMarkedForDeletion" : false,
    "ProductOldID" : "",
    "GrossWeight" : "0.000",
    "PurchaseOrderQuantityUnit" : "",
    "SourceOfSupply" : "",
    "WeightUnit" : "KG",
    "NetWeight" : "0.000",
    "CountryOfOrigin" : "",
    "CompetitorID" : "",
    "ProductGroup" : "01",
    "BaseUnit" : "EA",
    "ItemCategoryGroup" : "",
    "ProductHierarchy" : "",
    "Division" : "",
    "VarblPurOrdUnitIsActive" : "",
    "VolumeUnit" : "",
    "MaterialVolume" : "0.000",
    "ANPCode" : "0",
    "Brand" : "",
    "ProcurementRule" : "",
    "ValidityStartDate" : null,
    "LowLevelCode" : "",
    "ProdNoInGenProdInPrepackProd" : "",
    "SerialIdentifierAssgmtProfile" : "",
    "SizeOrDimensionText" : "",
    "IndustryStandardName" : "",
    "ProductStandardID" : "",
    "InternationalArticleNumberCat" : "",
    "ProductIsConfigurable" : false,
    "IsBatchManagementRequired" : false,
    "ExternalProductGroup" : "",
    "CrossPlantConfigurableProduct" : "",
    "SerialNoExplicitnessLevel" : "",   
    "ManufacturerPartProfile" : "",
    "ChangeNumber" : "",
    "MaterialRevisionLevel" : "",
    "HandlingIndicator" : "",
    "WarehouseProductGroup" : "",
    "WarehouseStorageCondition" : "",
    "StandardHandlingUnitType" : "",
    "SerialNumberProfile" : "",
    "AdjustmentProfile" : "",
    "PreferredUnitOfMeasure" : "",
    "IsPilferable" : false,
    "IsRelevantForHzdsSubstances" : false,
    "QuarantinePeriod" : "0",
    "TimeUnitForQuarantinePeriod" : "",
    "QualityInspectionGroup" : "",
    "AuthorizationGroup" : "",
    "HandlingUnitType" : "",
    "HasVariableTareWeight" : false,
    "MaximumPackagingLength" : "0.000",
    "MaximumPackagingWidth" : "0.000",
    "MaximumPackagingHeight" : "0.000",
  "to_Description": {
    "results": [
     {
        "Product" : "BALL",
        "Language" : "EN",
        "ProductDescription" : "Pipes for machines"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can u please help me how shall I modify my code to make deep insert with SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK work while using SAP Cloud Application Programming Model (`CreateRequest` class)?

**Log file:**

```
Product(super=VdmObject(customFields={}, changedOriginalFields={LowLevelCode=null, ProductGroup=null, SizeOrDimensionText=null, CreatedByUser=null, CountryOfOrigin=null, Product=null, ProductStandardID=null, IsPilferable=null, VolumeUnit=null, WarehouseProductGroup=null, WarehouseStorageCondition=null, MaterialVolume=null, ManufacturerPartProfile=null, CrossPlantStatus=null, TimeUnitForQuarantinePeriod=null, GrossWeight=null, InternationalArticleNumberCat=null, SourceOfSupply=null, ProductType=null, ItemCategoryGroup=null, ProcurementRule=null, BaseUnit=null, ProductOldID=null, VarblPurOrdUnitIsActive=null, LastChangedByUser=null, Brand=null, MaximumPackagingWidth=null, QuarantinePeriod=null, PurchaseOrderQuantityUnit=null, ProductHierarchy=null, AuthorizationGroup=null, StandardHandlingUnitType=null, MaterialRevisionLevel=null, ExternalProductGroup=null, CrossPlantConfigurableProduct=null, MaximumPackagingLength=null, HasVariableTareWeight=null, ANPCode=null, ProdNoInGenProdInPrepackProd=null, WeightUnit=null, IsMarkedForDeletion=null, CompetitorID=null, QualityInspectionGroup=null, IsBatchManagementRequired=null, IsRelevantForHzdsSubstances=null, Division=null, SerialIdentifierAssgmtProfile=null, AdjustmentProfile=null, PreferredUnitOfMeasure=null, SerialNoExplicitnessLevel=null, HandlingIndicator=null, HandlingUnitType=null, NetWeight=null, ProductIsConfigurable=null, IndustryStandardName=null, SerialNumberProfile=null, ChangeNumber=null, MaximumPackagingHeight=null}), product=BELL, productType=ZHLB, crossPlantStatus=, crossPlantStatusValidityDate=null, creationDate=null, createdByUser=11279380, lastChangeDate=null, lastChangedByUser=HWV87616, lastChangeDateTime=null, isMarkedForDeletion=false, productOldID=, grossWeight=0.000, purchaseOrderQuantityUnit=, sourceOfSupply=, weightUnit=KG, netWeight=0.000, countryOfOrigin=, competitorID=, productGroup=01, baseUnit=EA, itemCategoryGroup=, productHierarchy=, division=, varblPurOrdUnitIsActive=, volumeUnit=, materialVolume=0.000, aNPCode=0, brand=, procurementRule=, validityStartDate=null, lowLevelCode=, prodNoInGenProdInPrepackProd=, serialIdentifierAssgmtProfile=, sizeOrDimensionText=, industryStandardName=, productStandardID=, internationalArticleNumberCat=, productIsConfigurable=false, isBatchManagementRequired=false, externalProductGroup=, crossPlantConfigurableProduct=, serialNoExplicitnessLevel=, productManufacturerNumber=null, manufacturerNumber=null, manufacturerPartProfile=, changeNumber=, materialRevisionLevel=, handlingIndicator=, warehouseProductGroup=, warehouseStorageCondition=, standardHandlingUnitType=, serialNumberProfile=, adjustmentProfile=, preferredUnitOfMeasure=, isPilferable=false, isRelevantForHzdsSubstances=false, quarantinePeriod=0, timeUnitForQuarantinePeriod=, qualityInspectionGroup=, authorizationGroup=, handlingUnitType=, hasVariableTareWeight=false, maximumPackagingLength=0.000, maximumPackagingWidth=0.000, maximumPackagingHeight=0.000, erpConfigContext=null, toDescription=null, toPlant=null, toProductBasicText=null, toProductInspectionText=null, toProductProcurement=null, toProductPurchaseText=null, toProductQualityMgmt=null, toProductSales=null, toProductSalesTax=null, toProductStorage=null, toProductUnitsOfMeasure=null, toSalesDelivery=null)
{ "written_at":"2019-03-11T03:56:27.923Z","written_ts":918343802814688,"component_id":"e8c99eff-1a4e-4266-ba2a-fc099399100c","component_name":"FNpy7mXtvln0dnT1-FinalTestApp-srv","DCComponent":"","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"a78252bf-72bf-479c-b761-8260de0c776e","Application":"FNpy7mXtvln0dnT1-FinalTestApp-srv","container_id":"10.0.138.113","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.api.util.ProcessorHelper","thread":"http-nio-0.0.0.0-3000-exec-7","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 400.\nProvide atleast one description for the product.\nFull error message: \n{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": \"API_PRD_MSG/004\",\n    \"message\": {\n      \"lang\": \"en\",\n      \"value\": \"Provide atleast one description for the product.\"\n    },\n    \"innererror\": {\n      \"application\": {\n        \"component_id\": \"LO-MD-MM\",\n        \"service_namespace\": \"/SAP/\",\n        \"service_id\": \"API_PRODUCT_SRV\",\n        \"service_version\": \"0001\"\n      },\n      \"transactionid\": \"C16DD240C7520010E005C7E648BC12F5\",\n      \"timestamp\": \"20190311035627.5989630\",\n      \"Error_Resolution\": {\n        \"SAP_Transaction\": \"For backend administrators: run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details\",\n        \"SAP_Note\": \"See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)\"\n      },\n      \"errordetails\": [\n        {\n          \"code\": \"API_PRD_MSG/004\",\n          \"message\": \"Provide atleast one description for the product.\",\n          \"propertyref\": \"\",\n          \"severity\": \"error\",\n          \"target\": \"\"\n        }\n      ]\n    }\n  }\n}","stacktrace":["java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException","\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)","\tat
```

**my-service.cds**

```
    using API_PRODUCT_SRV  from '../srv/external/csn/API_PRODUCT_SRV.json';
    service ProductService {

      entity Products as Projection on API_PRODUCT_SRV.A_ProductType {
       key Product,
       ProductType,
       CreationDate,
       CrossPlantStatus,
       CrossPlantStatusValidityDate,
        CreatedByUser,
        LastChangeDate,
        LastChangedByUser,
        IsMarkedForDeletion,
        ProductOldID,
        GrossWeight,
        PurchaseOrderQuantityUnit,
        SourceOfSupply,
        WeightUnit,
        NetWeight,
        CountryOfOrigin,
        CompetitorID,
        ProductGroup,
        BaseUnit,
        ItemCategoryGroup,
        ProductHierarchy,
        Division,
        VarblPurOrdUnitIsActive,
        VolumeUnit,
        MaterialVolume,
        ANPCode,
        Brand,
        ProcurementRule,
        ValidityStartDate,
        LowLevelCode,
        ProdNoInGenProdInPrepackProd,
        SerialIdentifierAssgmtProfile,
        SizeOrDimensionText,
        IndustryStandardName,
        ProductStandardID,
        InternationalArticleNumberCat,
        ProductIsConfigurable,
        IsBatchManagementRequired,
        ExternalProductGroup,
        CrossPlantConfigurableProduct,
        SerialNoExplicitnessLevel,
        ProductManufacturerNumber,
        ManufacturerPartProfile,
        ChangeNumber,
        MaterialRevisionLevel,
        HandlingIndicator,
        WarehouseProductGroup,
        WarehouseStorageCondition,
        StandardHandlingUnitType,
        SerialNumberProfile,
        AdjustmentProfile,
        PreferredUnitOfMeasure,
       IsPilferable,
        IsRelevantForHzdsSubstances,
        QuarantinePeriod,
        TimeUnitForQuarantinePeriod,
        QualityInspectionGroup,
        AuthorizationGroup,
        HandlingUnitType,
        HasVariableTareWeight,
        MaximumPackagingLength,
        MaximumPackagingWidth,
        MaximumPackagingHeight,
      to_Description
      }
 entity A_ProductDescriptionType as Projection on API_PRODUCT_SRV.A_ProductDescriptionType
  {
              key  Product,
             key   Language,
                ProductDescription
}
}
```

**Can u please tell how to add associations in it?**
**my-service.cds**

```
using API_BUSINESS_PARTNER as bp from './external/csn/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER';

service CrudService{

 @cds.persistence.skip
 Entity BusinessPartner as projection on bp.A_BusinessPartnerType{
   BusinessPartner,
   LastName,
   FirstName,
   BusinessPartnerCategory
  };
}
```

Warm regards,

Meenakshi

Comment: Can you log or inspect the value of the `toCreate` object after you have used ModelMapper? Maybe it does not contain the description value you expect.

Comment: Hi Henning Heikotter,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                        
Sorry for the delayed response.Yes,you are correct.I printed toCreate Object.It is null.But I have included mydesciption associated entity in cds file.I have added log file and my-service.cds file

Comment: Can u please tell how to add associations in my-service.cds file?                             using API_BUSINESS_PARTNER as bp from './external/csn/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER';

service CrudService{

 @cds.persistence.skip
 Entity BusinessPartner as projection on bp.A_BusinessPartnerType{
   BusinessPartner,
   LastName,
   FirstName,
   BusinessPartnerCategory
  };
}

Comment: Can you also print the content of `req.getMapData()`? Does it contain the payload you expect?

Comment: No  it is not giving the right payload..It is only getting product entity data and not the product description data.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share your entire project if possible.  The request map may not be containing the product description data because I guess the association between the product and description is not defined properly in the CDS file.

Please check the following documentation to define your entities and associations:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/855e00bd559742a3b8276fbed4af1008.html

I am interested in knowing what is the $metadata response for your service currently.  Also, I would like to see your custom handler code and how you are trying to retrieve the deep insert payload from the request object.

Thanks,
Kranti

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your JSON **request** payload:

```
{
  "Product" : "BALL",
  ...
  "to_Description": {
    "results": [
     {
        "Product" : "BALL",
        "Language" : "EN",
        "ProductDescription" : "Pipes for machines"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*to_Description* is not expected to be an **object**. Instead it should be an **array**:

```
{
  "Product" : "BALL",
  ...
  "to_Description": [
     {
        "Product" : "BALL",
        "Language" : "EN",
        "ProductDescription" : "Pipes for machines"
     }
  ]
}
```